# How to compute mean of an 4D array individually?

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array `img` with shape is `64x128x512x3` that is concated from three images `64x128x512`. I want to compute mean of each image individually, given by the array `img`. Hence, I performed the code as bellows:

```
import numpy as np
img_means = np.mean(img, (0, 1, 2)))
```

Is it correct? My expected result is that `img_means[0,:,:,:]` is mean of the first image, `img_means[1,:,:,:]` is mean of second image, `img_means[2,:,:,:]` of third image.

Comment: This code calculates `img_means[i] = img[:,:,:,i].mean()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is correct, but note that `img_means` is just an array of three numbers (each one is the mean of the corresponding figure).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working in python 3.x
Do it like this:
First generate the data

```
import numpy as np
img=np.arange(64*128*512*3).reshape(64,128,512,3)
```

And this is what you want:

```
img_means=[img[:,:,:,i].mean() for i in range(img.shape[3]) ]
```

Comment: For me it worked on python 3 (python 3.5.2). Specifically with the following code: img=np.random.randint(5,size=(64,128,512,3))
b=np.mean(img,(0,1,2))